# NSDocument init not called in one pane of split view controller in a storyboard

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsdocument, nsstoryboard

I have a document-based application that works.

I added an `NSSplitViewController`, pointed the storyboard entry point to it, moved the document's view controller to a pane in the split view controller, and moved the document's view to one of the split view controller's views.  The other split view controller view will contain info that is not part of the document but will serve as a source for info that the user may add to the document.

Everything seems to work fine, except my document's `init` method is never called.  I don't understand enough about the application initialization process with respect to the storyboard to fix this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Are you linking your documents view controller in storyboard to a your class?

[image: Link storyboard to class]

Comment: My document's ViewController is linked to it's NSViewController subclass.  This ViewController's First Responder is shown to be my custom document.  I'm a little confused by your question.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In [myTableViewController viewDidLoad] I added an explicit call to [[Document alloc] init] which did the trick.

I still don't know why I did not have to do this in the simpler version, but I have to move on.  I've wasted too much time on this as it is.

Thanks for looking at this question.